# How to change background position using slideToggle callback

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Hopefully I am missing something relatively straight forward here.
I am hoping to have the first click toggle the background position of an image -37px and then the second click toggle back to the original position.

I am changing a plus sign to a minus sign and then back to a plus sign as a div is shown and hidden.

Thanks for the help!

```
$('#expand-button').click(function() {
    $('#top10-list').slideToggle(600, function() {
        $('#expand-button').css('background-position','0 -37px');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/ibijey/edit#javascript,html,live

```
$('#expand-button').toggle(function() {
    $('#top10-list').slideToggle(600, function() {
        $('#expand-button').css('background-position','0 -37px');
    });
},function(){
    $('#top10-list').slideToggle(600, function() {
        $('#expand-button').css('background-position','0 0px');
    });
});
```

Comment: I really can't wait until the day I don't have to ask for help to do simple functions! Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @AdamPflantzer YOu're welcome! here you have a demo http://jsbin.com/ibijey/edit#javascript,html,live Happy coding!